# necessary and sufficient conditions for inversibility of a specific positive semi-definite matrix

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

For some integers $n$ and $K$, nonnegative scalars $(\lambda_a)_{1 \leq a \leq K}$ and vectors $(y_a)_{1 \leq a \leq K} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, consider the matrix $$A:=\sum_{a=1}^{K}\lambda_ay_ay_a^T.$$
The matrix A is clearly positive semi-definite. What are some conditions on $\lambda$ and $y$ for $A$ to actually be positive definite (i.e. when is it invertible) ?

Comment: We may omit the terms corresponding to $\lambda_a=0,$ hence we may assume tha $\lambda_a>0$ for any $a.$ A necessary and sufficient condition is that the vectors $y_a$ span the whole space, i.e. there is no vector  orthogonal to all $y_a.$

Comment: great, thank you!